# how to reload /usr/lib/lua/luci/dispatcher.lua after a modification without restart the board?

Tags: lua, openwrt, luci

Queston:
on an openwrt board I've done some adhoc modification to some luci files i.e. /usr/lib/lua/luci/dispatcher.lua, how can it be reloaded into use without a total restart of the board?

Answer (score 2):

I've found the answer myself with a little googling:

```
uci set luci.ccache.enable=0
uci commit luci
```

at the command line

or

simply remove `/tmp/.luci-indexcache`.